# Pessimistic locking fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, pessimistic-locking

I have the following code in my controller:

```
Item.transaction do
  item = JobDistribution.lock(true).find(params[:id])
  item.update_attributes(status: JobDistribution.statuses[:processing])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => "object processing", status: :success }
  end
end
```

but when I run the code I'm getting the error:

> Attempted to update a stale object: Item

I don't understand why, I followed the rails documentation.

Comment: From which documentation do you have this? You are trying to override new data with old, while the new is locked.

Comment: @Robin http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html

Comment: Do you have a `lock_version` column? Is it the latest number, when you try to run your transaction?

Comment: @Robin I do have a lock version column and here is the failing sql query: `UPDATE "items" SET "status" = 1, "updated_at" = '2015-11-04 11:54:36.422768', "lock_version" = 1 WHERE ("items"."id" = 35 AND "items"."lock_version" = 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lock_version` is for optimistic locking, you're also using pessimistic locking with chaining your `find` from the `lock`. Rails is getting confused between the two - pick one or the other.